# outlook sent mails

Tags: c#

Hi i want to get outlook sent attachments and recipient subject of the mail sent... i am able to get it by Default Folders of outlook.
How can i retrieve the sent mails by VSTO before the mails is being sent.

now i am doing so

```
namespace OutlookAddInAttachment
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisApplication_NewMail);

    }

    private void ThisApplication_NewMail()
    {
        Outlook.MAPIFolder SentMail = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
        Outlook.Items SentMailItems = SentMail.Items;
        Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
        //SentMailItems = SentMailItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
        try
        {
            foreach (object collectionItem in SentMailItems)
            {
                newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                if (newEmail != null)
                {
                    if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i++)
                        {
                            newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(@"C:\TestFileSave\" + newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorInfo = (string)ex.Message
                .Substring(0, 11);
            if (errorInfo == "Cannot save")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Create Folder C:\TestFileSave");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here.

You're listening to the NewMail event, which listens for new RECEIVED mail in the INBOX, and then scans the Sent Items folder, which contains, by definition, only items that have already been sent.

If what you're trying to do is intercept the attachemnts of new mail being sent, what you need is the [ItemSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147641%28v=office.12%29.aspx) event, which will allow you to catch it in action, before it's sent:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(ThisApplication_ItemSend);
}

private void ThisApplication_ItemSend(object item, bool cancel)
{
    Outlook.MailItem newEmail = item as MailItem;
    if (newEmail != null)
    {
        foreach (var attachment in newEmail.Attachments)
        {
            attachment.SaveAsFile(@"C:\TestFileSave\" + attachment.FileName);
        }
    }
}

}
```